# Running query inside loop

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter-3

Good day. I'm trying to running a query inside `loop`. Here is what i did so far.

```
function scan_folder()
{       
    $this->load->library('Word');

    $this->load->helper('directory');
    $map2 = directory_map('./assets/filenya/Hukum Acara', TRUE, TRUE);
    for($x=0;$x<count($map2);$x++)
            {
                    $map3 = directory_map('./assets/filenya/Hukum Acara/'.$map2[$x]);
                    for($xy = 0;$xy<count($map3);$xy++)
                    {

                        $category[$xy] = $this->modelmodel->showsingle("SELECT menu_id FROM kategori 
                                                                where name like '%".stripslashes($map2[$x])."%'");
                        echo $map3[$xy]." ".$category[$xy]->menu_id."<br>";
                    }
            }
}
```

with my script above. I get this error `Trying to get property of non-object`.

Array from `$map2`

```
Array
(
    [0] => H.I.R\
    [1] => Kitab Undang-Undang Hukum\
)
```

array from `$map3`

```
Array
(
    [0] => KOLONIAL_HERZIEN_INLANDSCH_REGLEMENT.pdf
)
Array
(
    [0] => kolonial_kuh_perdata_fix.pdf
    [1] => KUH DAGANG.pdf
    [2] => KUH PIDANA.pdf
    [3] => KUHAP.pdf
)
```

And if i just echo the query

```
echo "SELECT menu_id FROM kategori 
  where name like '%".stripslashes($map2[$x])."%' <br>";
```

and here is the result

```
SELECT menu_id FROM kategori where name like '%H.I.R%' 
SELECT menu_id FROM kategori where name like '%Kitab Undang-Undang Hukum%' 
SELECT menu_id FROM kategori where name like '%Kitab Undang-Undang Hukum%' 
SELECT menu_id FROM kategori where name like '%Kitab Undang-Undang Hukum%' 
SELECT menu_id FROM kategori where name like '%Kitab Undang-Undang Hukum%'
```

here is my error . I'm using Codeigniter 3

> KOLONIAL_HERZIEN_INLANDSCH_REGLEMENT.pdf 11 A PHP Error was
>   encountered
>
> Severity: Notice
>
> Message: Trying to get property of non-object
>
> Filename: controllers/Admin.php
>
> Line Number: 31
>
> Backtrace:
>
> File: D:\xampp\htdocs\jdih\application\controllers\Admin.php Line: 31
>   Function: _error_handler
>
> File: D:\xampp\htdocs\jdih\index.php Line: 315 Function: require_once
>
> kolonial_kuh_perdata_fix.pdf  A PHP Error was encountered
>
> Severity: Notice
>
> Message: Trying to get property of non-object
>
> Filename: controllers/Admin.php
>
> Line Number: 31
>
> Backtrace:
>
> File: D:\xampp\htdocs\jdih\application\controllers\Admin.php Line: 31
>   Function: _error_handler
>
> File: D:\xampp\htdocs\jdih\index.php Line: 315 Function: require_once
>
> KUH DAGANG.pdf  A PHP Error was encountered
>
> Severity: Notice
>
> Message: Trying to get property of non-object
>
> Filename: controllers/Admin.php
>
> Line Number: 31
>
> Backtrace:
>
> File: D:\xampp\htdocs\jdih\application\controllers\Admin.php Line: 31
>   Function: _error_handler
>
> File: D:\xampp\htdocs\jdih\index.php Line: 315 Function: require_once
>
> KUH PIDANA.pdf  A PHP Error was encountered
>
> Severity: Notice
>
> Message: Trying to get property of non-object
>
> Filename: controllers/Admin.php
>
> Line Number: 31
>
> Backtrace:
>
> File: D:\xampp\htdocs\jdih\application\controllers\Admin.php Line: 31
>   Function: _error_handler
>
> File: D:\xampp\htdocs\jdih\index.php Line: 315 Function: require_once
>
> KUHAP.pdf

Comment: Which line causes `Trying to get property of non-object` ?

Comment: post your whole error info

Comment: I think in this line $category[$xy]->menu_id;

Comment: i've put the error.

Comment: Which in line 31 ?

Comment: this part echo $map3[$xy]." ".$category[$xy]->menu_id."<br>";

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give a try with this

```
for($x=0;$x<count($map2);$x++)
            {
                    $map3 = directory_map('./assets/filenya/Hukum Acara/'.$map2[$x]);
                    foreach($map3 as $file)
                    {

                        $category = $this->modelmodel->showdata("SELECT menu_id FROM kategori 
                                                                where name like '%".stripslashes($map2[$x])."%'");
                         foreach($category as $result)
                            {
                                echo $file."--".$result->menu_id."<br>";
                            }
                    }
            }
```